# How do I use Mindee API with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm just playing about with code and interested in parsing receipts to text (end point csv file). I came across this tutorial on mindee API where they also provide code to run the parsing. However, I keep getting the below errors when attempting to parse.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.mindee.net/v1/products/mindee/expense_receipts/v3/predict"

with open("/Users/test/PycharmProjects/PythonCrashCourse", "rb") as myfile: # Here they mention to specify the PATH to file/files which is here as per my windows10 path.
    files = {"IMG_5800.jpg": myfile}
    headers = {"Authorization": "Token asdasd21321"}
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/test/PycharmProjects/PythonCrashCourse'
```

Why is there permission denied? When I am admin and have full permissions enabled on the file iteself.
I have also tried modifying the code and running the below;

```
import requests

url = "https://api.mindee.net/v1/products/mindee/expense_receipts/v3/predict"
imageFile = "IMG_5800.jpg" #File is in the current directory
files = {"file": open(imageFile, "rb")}

headers = {"Authorization": "Token a4342343c925a"}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

#output

```
  {"api_request":{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","details":{"document":["Missing data for required field."],"file":["Unknown field."]},"message":"Invalid fields in form"},"resources":[],"status":"failure","**status_code":400**,"url":"http://api.mindee.net/v1/products/mindee/expense_receipts/v3/predict"}}
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Status code 400 - suggests something has gone wrong with the syntax....Unfortunately I am stuck and simply just want the API to parse my receipt. Any ideas on what is going wrong please?

Desired output:

- get results from receipt in text format/json from Mindee API

References Used:

- https://medium.com/mindeeapi/extract-receipt-data-with-mindees-api-using-python-7ee7303f4b6d tutorial on Mindee API
- https://platform.mindee.com/products/mindee/expense_receipts?setup=default#documentation

Comment: I assume you have satisfied all prerequisites as defined by tutorial to include: (1) setup a Mindee account and confirmed your email to login? (2)IMG_5800.jpg" contains a receipt image? (3) You have verified that you can open image from your current working directory?  (4) login in to the mindee account and entered your Expense receipt API environment? (4) placed your newly created token where indicated in the ```headers = {"X-Inferuser-Token": "my-token-here"} ``` line?

Comment: Yes, I have setup a Mindee account (step1), step 2 yes is an image which works on the Mindee website API. Step 3, yes can open the image from current directory. Step 4, yes entered Mindee Receipt environment, created API key and they even have a code snippet they provide for Python which I copied. Step 4) Yes as per headers = {"Authorization": "Token a4342343c925a"}

Comment: Similarly - I've used Aspire API to achieve the same which is working but reason Im trying Mindee - is simply they allow me to make 250 free calls to the API whilst, Aspire only 5. ```receiptOcrEndpoint = 'https://ocr.asprise.com/api/v1/receipt' 
imageFile = "IMG_5805.jpg" 
r = requests.post(receiptOcrEndpoint, data = { \
  'client_id': 'TEST',        # Use 'TEST' for testing purpose \
  'recognizer': 'auto',       # can be 'US', 'CA', 'JP', 'SG' or 'auto' \
  }, \
  files = {"file": open(imageFile, "rb")})
print(r.text) # result in JSON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it was stated that the document was missing.

I'm glad you found the solution to this.

However, following the [documentation](https://developers.mindee.com/docs/receipt-ocr), there is an improved code, the  authentication header `X-Inferuser-Token` has been deprecated.

You can try doing this instead

```
import requests

url = "https://api.mindee.net/v1/products/mindee/expense_receipts/v3/predict"

with open("./IMG_5800.jpg", "rb") as myfile:
    files = {"document": myfile}
    headers = {"Authorization": "Token my-api-key-here"}
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Favour - I indeed should use 'Authorization' as opposed to 'x-inferuser'.

Answer (score 0):

After brushing up on HTML format - https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/HTML+file+path. I realised the path I used was wrong and should've used the correct HTML format whether I am on Windows/Mac.
To resolve my issue, I mentioned to go 1 directory up to where the image file is, when running my code.

```
with open("./IMG_5800.jpg", "rb") as myfile: #modified here to go 1 directory up to where the image file is hosted
    files = {"file": myfile}
    headers = {"X-Inferuser-Token": "Token my-api-key-here"}
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```